# Best way to pass variables from one Swift class to another?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Suppose I define variable in one class, `ViewController`, and want to access that variable from another class, say `BLEHandler`.  How do I go about doing that?  I've had trouble with `NSUserDefaults`, so a method besides that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not having problems with NSUserDefaults you are having problems with your BLEHandler

Comment: What have you tried, and what results did you get?  Why isn't `NSUserDefaults` working out for you?  What's `BLEHandler`?  Why can't it hold a reference to the view controller?  This question is way too broad.

Comment: [Looks like an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is for persisting application data. I would suggest making a singleton class  and putting those state-full properties on it.

Comment: I'm not sure the blanket recommendation of a singleton (without more information about the user's specific scenario) is that much better than RandallTo's answer, @cream-corn ...

Comment: this is true, but I would argue that RandallTo's solution is to use the app delegate as a singleton. "Its global to your view controllers." either way; You are correct, we don't actually know if a singleton will solve this problem. based on the info OP provided @nhgrif

Comment: Yes, that's what RandallTo's suggestion is... and that's part of why it's bad.  App Delegate is definitely worse than a separate singleton... but if possible, the `BLEHandler` should probably just have some direct reference to whatever it needs...

Comment: @nhgrif  agree totally. I was too hasty in proposing a solution without having enough info to form one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are may ways you can pass value between viewControllers
For example

- PrepareForSegue
- NSNotificationCenter
- Delegate
- Singleton

Different way is used in different case.

**If you use prepareFoSegue**- is used when you want to pass when perform segue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        //Use below to get reference,so that you can pass value
        //segue.destinationViewController 
        //segue.sourceViewController
}
```

**If you use notificationcenter** - blind notification,one vc send message,may more than one to receive.
In send message vc

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(, object: )
```

In receive message vc
Register first

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(, selector: , name: , object: )
```

Than you get the value from the selector

Do not forget to remove

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(, name: , object:  )
```

**If you use delegate** - the receiver and sender has a connection first.
There are may post about this,I will not post example.

**If you use singleton** - you have to be clear about the life circle of singleton. I do not suggest to pass value in this way.

Comment: Just to cover all bases, recommend all possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't worry**

```
var firstmyvar = "Any"

let secondview = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("secondview") as SecondViewController

secondview.myvar = firstmyvar

self.presentViewController(secondview, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -4):

One way is to create a variable in app delegate. Its global to your view controllers.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let aVariable = appDelegate.someVariable
```

Comment: While this would work, it's bad advice and I have to downvote it.

Comment: This is extremely bad practise. "You can judge the quality of an iOS app by how long the app delegate is"

Comment: The question is not clear enough if the if the app is using storyboards custom UIViewControllers or how it is architected. Hence the reason for stating, "This is one way .." not this is the best for your context because I don't know the context.