# Presenting an alert from a view controller that has closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have an iOS Objective-C application in which I am attempting to show a UIAlertController, from a UIViewController which is in the process of closing. I have tried adding this common workaround in `AppDelegate`:

```
- (UIViewController *)currentTopViewController
{
   UIViewController *topVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
   while (topVC.presentedViewController)
   {
     topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
   }
  return topVC;
}
```

Called with:

```
[appDelegate.currentTopViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However this error is still appearing:

```
Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController on MyViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: You should send a notification (or use delegation, etc.) to the parent viewcontroller and present it from there

Comment: @nathan Could you provide an example of using a notification?

Comment: Example of delegation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33229483/2124535, NotificationCenter example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29738348/2124535

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display an alert upon closing a viewcontroller, then you can just implement dismiss with completion block and display it there. For example:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {
  // UIAlertController code here

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIWindow with a transparent UIViewController and then presenting the UIAlertController on it.
Below link provides a category on UIAlertController that has a show method in Objective-C. You can use it.

Link: [How to present UIAlertController when not in a view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller)